# Rhythmbox will no longer attach to launcher

Tags: gnome, rhythmbox

I have been reorganizing my launcher. Now Rhythmbox will no longer attach to it when it is minimized.

So when I want to skip past ads on my favorite podcast, I have to go up there to the menubar, find that tiny little triangle (the Rhythmbox window will not appear unless I click directly on the little triangle), and then the Rhythmbox GUI window appears from the middle of the desktop, move the slider to skip past the ads, and then minimize it so that I can get back to what I am working on with a clean desktop.

This is inconvenient.

How can I re-familiarize Rhythmbox with the launcher?

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).